# Sometimes, I cannot enter certain lowercase characters. What is wrong?

Tags: 22.04, keyboard

A few days or weeks ago, something very strange happened in my daily work with `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS`. Suddenly my keyboard keys <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Q</kbd> started to show a random behaviour.

When I pressed the keys, not a single `d`, `r` or `q` was written, but pressing the <kbd>`Shift`</kbd> key and <kbd>`D`</kbd>, <kbd>`R`</kbd> or <kbd>`Q`</kbd> *always* worked.

The problem still persists. What can I do to make it go away?

Comment: Did you possibly log in entering your username in all-caps? If so, the system would then assume that you cannot enter lower-case characters and will give the described behavior.

Comment: No, I dind’t. The described behaviour started to occur “out of nothing” a few days or weeks ago.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "sometimes"? Does this happen in all applications, or only specific ones?

Comment: This happens with all applications. “Sometimes” means that one moment there is no problem at all entering these characters and then suddenly one pops up. *(When I wrote this comment, I was trying to type the word “there” and “theer” appeared on the screen. It may be that some processes are interfering with these three keyboard keys, but I don’t know which processes are responsible for this chaos.)*

Comment: Try to remind yourself if you have installed new software, or updated just before this began. Add any info on that to your positing.

Comment: Using an external keyboard (instead of my laptop keyboard) works fine. But I don’t think that my laptop keyboard has some kind of hardware issue. If that were the case, the problem would look differently.

Comment: @Hannu I cannot remember that I have installed anything new. If that were the case, I would have considered it to be responsible for this issue but nothing has come to my mind. Maybe some weird update caused the issue. I don’t know whether this is the case or not. Maybe my recent comment can give you and the others additional information that is valuable in order to solve the problem.

Comment: As the external keyboard works, I'd say the internal keyboard is highly suspect, or the cabling to it.

Comment: It may be the case that it is related to some internal keyboard hardware issue. But the error is pretty atypical for such an issue. If it really were a hardware issue, wouldn’t the problems also occur if I wrote `D`, `R` or `Q`?